# How do i fix the Linux terminal while using gcc in Vscode

Tags: c, gcc

Image reference of actual issue:
[image]

The terminal's prompt is printed on the same line as the last of my program's output.
Can this be fixed? I want the terminal's prompt to appear on the next line after output.

Also, I am executing this code using code runner extension in terminal.

Comment: add a new line `\n` at the end of your print statement

Comment: i know that, but want a permanent fix

Comment: Adding newline to the output is quite permanent.

Comment: if your program does not add a newline you can add it to your shell prompt, but then  you will complain that there are empty lines with programs that add a closing newline, like all the unix tools/commands

Comment: ok then will follow old school

Comment: you can add it conditionally to your shell prompt but then the people using your program will complain, get in the habit of ending each `printf` (block, in case you print some table output) with a newline, then the following `printf` will start at the beginning of a line. And so does the terminal prompt. That is doing it the C shool way.

Comment: It is nothing like "old school", it is a very acceptable and common thing.

Comment: you might be used to other languages that always end a print/log/output statement with a newline by default (Python), but C is much more: `you get what you command me`, you can create a `printfnl` function that adds the newline by default, you need to use `vararg`

Comment: Most useful C programs are more than 12 lines of code, and having some method of consistency will help you a lot, also working on other peoples code, yes that will be the case in your programmer working life a lot